# How to make whole textarea readable on using link..using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code in my view..

```
<span class="bold">Comment:
  <%=Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, new { })%>
</span>
```

The comment field is populating from a database. The text from the database is too long to fit in the visible area of the textarea. I have been asked to create a link next to the text area that, when clicked, would display the entire contents of the textarea in a 'popup bubble'.

Is this possible using jQuery?

Comment: So did your question ever get answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

**See it on jsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/GmBqy/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("a.viewtext").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var textarea = $($(this).attr("href"));
          var popup = $("<div class='popup'><span class='close'>Close</span></div>");
          var closeButton = $("<span class='close'>Close</span>").appendTo(popup);
          closeButton.click(function() {
           $(this).closest(".popup").remove();                                                                                  
          });
          $("<div></div>").text(textarea.val()).appendTo(popup);
          textarea.after(popup);
        });
      });
    </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  .popup {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      left: 10%;
      width: 50%;
      background: #eee;
      border: solid 5px #000;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
  }
  .popup div {
      padding: 20px;
  }
  .popup .close {
      font: bold 11px sans-serif;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: #333;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 3px 6px;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="myTextField">It is a long established fact that 
  a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page 
  when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is 
  that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as 
  opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look.
  </textarea>
  <a class="viewtext" href="#myTextField">View Contents</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did the textare something like this.. But I am not getting the textarea value into popup window?
  <a class="viewtext" href="#myTextField">More...</a>
          <span id="myTextField"><%=Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, new { })%></span>

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle.net? That would make it much easier to help you fix the code. Otherwise it is pretty much impossible to figure out what is wrong from the small snippet you posted.

Comment: @rockers try changing '<a class="viewtext" href="#myTextField">View Contents</a>' to '<a class="viewtext" href="#Comment">View Contents</a>'.  The href value should be the # sign plus whatever the id attribute is on your textarea (do a 'view source' to find that out)

Answer (score 2):

Lets break your problem up into two parts; get the value from the textarea and display the value in a tooltip.

Using the current stackoverflow "Your Answer" form as a sample form, start entering a new answer and then run this in your browser's console:

```
$("#wmd-input").val()
```

For me it looks a little something like this right now:

> "Lets break your problem up ...

Now you have to decide how to display your tooltip with [one](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) of the [many](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) [available](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/) [options](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) (or just roll your own).

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is in fact possible.

Comment: I was tempted to leave the exact same snarky answer. But I refrained.

Answer (score 1):

You could create another property on your model for the shortened comment text and then store the full comment text in a hidden span.

Here is an example to get you started:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .commentFullText {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.showFullComment').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().find('.commentFullText').show();
    });
  });
</script>

<span class="bold">Comment:
  <%=Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CommentShortened, new { })%>
  <a href="#" class="showFullComment">More...</a>
  <span class="commentFullText"><%=Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, new { })%></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Not sure how that is possible since the link has `href="#"` but check out @jessegavin's answer, it is a more complete example doing exactly what you described.